# как написать протокол 3 уровня сетевой модели OSI

Tags: c#, c++, сеть, протоколы

Я сам сетевой администратор, понимаю как работает сеть, но я не понимаю каким образом реализуется написание такого протокола как например IP или ICMP. Я наталкивался на коды описывающие это, но мой вопрос чуть глубже а именно:

1. Необходимо ли воздействовать на драйвер сетевой карты или требуется написать свой драйвер?
2. Каким образом я регистрирую протокол на пк? А именно в каком виде хранятся протоколы на пк? Насколько я знаю протоколы в маршрутизаторах зашиты в ОС роутера.
3. Насколько я знаю в виндовс имеется сектор коммуникации (WINRT) имеется ли необходимость воздействия с этим сектором и как это делать.
4. Я знаю, что это частично невозможно, но я хочу попытаться разработать его с помощью c#. Я знаю что с++ это скальпель программиста но совсем нет желания сейчас изучать дополнительный язык.
5. Какого рода программирование следует использовать, структурное, объектное?

Comment: *изучать дополнительный язык* -- русский?

Comment: 13 лет как не живу в россие

Comment: прошу ответы по теме

Comment: Можно использовать Winpcap который позволит вам формировать пакеты вручную, и реализовать свой протокол, который может быть доступен другим приложениям через вашу dll.

Comment: 1) посмотреть как реализовано можно на примере исходников сетевого стека Linux, надеюсь объяснять сетевому админу где и как найти эти  исходники не надо. 2) C# язык создан для быстрого написания прикладного софта, а не системного, фактически C# - это инструмент для "управления" дотнет фреймворком - посредником между собственно ОС и вашей прикладной программой. Для написания сетевого стека же требуется прямой, без посредников даже в виде API ОС доступ к железу (сетевой карте), потому только C или C++. Хотя , работу с железом легче всего реализовать в процедурном стиле, так что C.